# Convert to UInt32 in Swift from NS_ENUM uint32_t in Objective-C

Tags: swift, objective-c, enums, uint32, uint32-t

I have this code...

Objective-c:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(uint32_t, EXType) {
  EXTypeBad = 0,
  EXTypeOK,
  EXTypeGood
};

EXType type = EXTypeOK;
```

Swift

```
 UInt32(type)
```

But I get:

> initializer 'init(_:radix:)' requires that 'EXType' conform to
> 'StringProtocol'
> type: UInt32(type)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `type.rawValue`?

Comment: hah yeah it worked. I swear I tried that. My dang autocomplete doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the rawValue property on the NSEnum. My Autocomplete didn't suggest this to me.

```
UInt32(type.rawValue)
```

Comment: No need to initialize another object from it. It is redundant.`type.rawValue` would suffice. It returns an `UInt32` object aleeady.